# Prohibit direct extension of Java class outside its package

Tags: java, inheritance, api-design

I have a package with a

```
public abstract class Player { /*...*/ }
```

and these

```
public abstract class GamePlayer extends Player { /*...*/ }
public abstract class TournamentPlayer extends Player { /*...*/ }
public abstract class StatelessPlayer extends Player { /*...*/ }
```

Users of the package need Players but in order to use the package without breaking it I require that they never *directly* extend Player.  Instead they should extend one of the subclasses provided.

Question: How should I prevent users from extending Player directly?

I'm looking for a way that makes it obvious that this prohibition is intended.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make the constructors in `Player` have package access only. Then they won't be able to call the constructor or extend it themselves. If you don't already *have* an explicit constructor in `Player`, create one (as otherwise the compiler will create a default public parameterless constructor).

(Note that I've only suggested doing this to the *constructor*. The class itself can be public so that clients can still use it.)

This works because any constructor (other than in `java.lang.Object`) has to call a superclass constructor (either explicitly or implicitly). If there are no accessible constructors, you can't create the subclass.

Comment: +1 for the note about the implicit public default constructor

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the constructors of Player are not public:

```
public abstract class Player {
    Player() {
        // initialization goes here
    }
}
```

Then classes can extend Player from within the same package, but should not be able to from outside of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default access modifier, also known as "Package private" access.  In other words, don't specify an access modifier

```
abstract class Player { /*...*/ }
```

The [documentation here at Sun's website](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) describes all of the access modifiers in greater detail.

Comment: But then will clients even be able to see the class?  Sorry I don't have a javac handy to check myself.

Comment: No, they won't - which is why it should only be the constructor which is non-public.

Comment: an alternative might be a public interface, combined with the package-private abstract base class...

Comment: eh, Jon Skeet is correct, as I knee-jerk answered that without realizing the class still needs to be publicly available.  

Alnitak's suggestion is quite good also.

Answer (score 0):

Um... make the Player class non-public? Just leave out "public", then it will be package-private, i.e. only classes in the same package can extend it.

However, nothing outright prevents people from putting their own classes in that package. I believe it's possible to prevent it by putting it into a signed JAR, then any attempt to load an unsigned (or differently-signed) class in the same package will fail.

Comment: I believe that prevents *use* outside the package as well as, not just inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend

- Create public interfaces for things you want clients to access but not create or subclass
- Create public classes for things you want clients to access *and* create or subclass
- anything else should be non-public

The problem with this approach is that you end up with everything needing to be in a single package, which is bad for organization as the library grows.

To allow use of multiple packages with protection, take a look at OSGi.

OSGi allows you to restrict which packages a bundle (jar) allows other bundles to access, and even set up "friend" bundles that are allowed extra visibility.

Java's package-as-protection-unit model is not sufficient when you really want to protect libraries that get large...